# How can I get rid of an empty Drive Letter?

Tags: windows-8

How can I get rid of an empty Drive Letter?

Whenever I open my file explorer (the same applies with the default Windows Explorer), I always get this prompt message - "There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive I:"

I can get through by clicking "Continue", but my question is, how can I remove that empty Drive?

---

CubicExplorer.exe - No Disk

"There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive I:"

### Cancel - Try Again - Continue

---

Location is not available

I:\ is not accessible.

### The device is not ready.

---

Computer

- Local Disk (C:)
- Local Disk (D:)
- Local Disk (E:)
- CD Drive (F:) Sky Broadband
- DVD RW Drive (G:)
- Removable Disk (H:)
- Local Disk (I:)                "This is the problem Drive Letter, its empty"
- MyUSB (Z:)

---

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Two place to check, Press the Windows Key and type `devmgmt.msc` and and again with `diskmgmt.msc`, the first Windows shows all your hardware. Check under 'Disk drives', the second Window shows the disk drives in detail. This may give you a hint about what kind of drive your explorers are complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Explorer click on the tab View and then uncheck the radio button Hidden Items. Now you will not see the empty Drive Letters anymore.

[image: Hide Empty Drive Letters]

---

### Microsoft Solution

To resolve the issue, use one of the following methods:

- Insert a removable disk in the removable drive before you start the computer.
- Change the drive letter assignment for the removable drive to a
  letter other than C.

To change the drive letter assignments in Windows XP, follow these steps:

1. Log on to the computer as Administrator.
2. Insert a disk in the removable drive.
3. Click Start, right-click My Computer, and then click Manage.
4. Click Disk Management.
5. Right-click the partition, logical drive, or volume that you want to
   change, and then click Change Drive Letter and Paths.
6. Click the removable drive, click it, click Change, click the drive
   letter that you want to use, and then click OK.

The Microsoft Article can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/330137)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and i solve it....

1. type "Regedt32.exe" in start
2. open "Regedt32.exe"
3. Go to "HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3663309149-4163902786-1989769739-1000\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DriveIcons

   "I just searched the name i want remove it"

   4. you will find the letter under "DriveIcons"
   5. open "DefaultLabel" under the letter and delete (Default) name
   6. maybe you need to restart PC "for me i didn't"